# Have the words "Bad Wolf" or "Blaidd Drwg" been seen since the 11th Doctor took over the TARDIS?

Tags: doctor-who

Have the words **Bad Wolf** shown up anywhere in the 11th Doctor's time?

If not, when was the last time they were seen in Doctor Who (as of July 2012)?

Comment: Also (I'm probably pushing it at this point, but) perhaps you might consider switching your acceptance, since the currently accepted answer by chcuk is now out of date? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor It is not out of date. your answer is not relevant to this question. It was asked in 2012. The question asks if any references were made up until July of 2012. Your answer is _technically_ wrong...

Comment: So you want your question to remain only relevant to 2012 and never be updated? If that were the case, it might as well be deleted at this point.

Comment: Part of the idea of Stack Exchange sites is that their information stays up-to-date (that’s why questions and answers are always editable). You *can* ask about a specific time period, but with this question I don’t see a need to make it so temporally specific (although of course, I’m not a Time Lord).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of today (mid-2016), the only time the words "Bad Wolf" have appeared since the Tennant era was during the 50th anniversary special, which commemorated all sorts of things from Whovian history and featured the return of David Tennant and Billie Piper themselves:

> MOMENT: I hear you. All of you, jangling around in that dusty old head of yours. I chose this face and form especially for you. It's from your past. Or possibly your future. I always get those two mixed up.
>   WARRIOR: I don't have a future.
>   MOMENT: I think I'm called Rose Tyler. No. Yes. No, sorry, no, no, in this form, I'm called **Bad Wolf**. Are you afraid of the big **bad wolf**, Doctor?
>
> [...]
>
> WARRIOR: She didn't just show me any old future, she showed me exactly the future I needed to see.
>   MOMENT: Now you're getting it.
>   DOCTOR: Eh? Who did?
>   WARRIOR: Oh, **Bad Wolf** girl, I could kiss you.
>   MOMENT: Yeah, that's going to happen.
>   DOCTOR 10: Sorry, did you just say **Bad Wolf**?
>
> <sub>-- *The Day of the Doctor* (emphasis mine)</sub>

This can be verified by [searching the Chakoteya transcript archive](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?id=98804524&pageid=r&mode=ALL&n=0&_charset_=UTF-8&bcd=%C3%B7&scs=1&q1=&q2=bad+wolf&q3=&q4=&rpp=10&dl=m&stm=) for the phrase "Bad Wolf" - the only results are *The Day of the Doctor* and a bunch of episodes from Series 1-4.

Answer (score 18):

The last time Bad wolf was shown was during episode 12 of series 4 "Turn Left", where Donna accidentally created a new universe by turning left instead of right and Rose came and told her to let the doctor know that the stars were going out.  When they walk out of the tent after the beetle falls off of Donna's back all the signs in the chinese market where they were, read "Bad Wolf".  This occurs during the last 2:30 min of that episode.

[image: Image of Bad Wolf]